# Create Unique constraint on Postgres with .NET core 3 and Npgsql (code first)

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, npgsql

I am trying to set a Unique constraint on a table column using Npgsql EF Core Provider.

In the below snippet, `HasDefaultValueSql` works fine but `HasIndex(i => i.ItemCode).IsUnique()` has no effect on the generated migrations and there's no index created on the **ItemCode** field.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.UseSnakeCaseNames();
  modelBuilder.HasPostgresExtension("uuid-ossp");

  modelBuilder.Entity<InventoryStockItem>().Property(p => p.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("uuid_generate_v4()");
  modelBuilder.Entity<InventoryStockItem>().HasIndex(i => i.ItemCode).IsUnique();

  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: I have tryed your code and it worked fine. Have you checked, in the __EFMigrationsHistory table, if the migration script was not already launched ?